# custom periods value is not taking for linear indicator in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm need linear type technical indicator([Linear](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/16/technical-indicators/)) with custom set periods value not the default value '100'.

So, I have created this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/Am6pu/) for the same with custom periods value '70'.

```
{
    name: 'Linear Trendline',
    linkedTo: 'primary',
    showInLegend: true,
    enableMouseTracking: true,
    type: 'trendline',
    algorithm: 'linear',
    periods:70
}
```

But this does not take any effect. the periods value is still taking 100. what I did wrong?

Comment: I advice to contact with the plugin's author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is sparse but from a quick look at the source, the `period` parameter is how many points to include in (*the window size of*) the moving average.  The `linear` algorithm type, though, is a regression line.  It fits to all the data points and by definition does not have a window size.

Comment: So what should I do?? I mean how do I pass custom periods value?

Comment: @Poles, you don't, for a regression line, it doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do, can you illustrate how you want it to look?

Comment: Ok...I misunderstood your answer. Sorry, Now I totally get it. There is no period value for the regression line right?